# An HTML form is being submitted despite returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form which is being submitted no matter the alert and the return false statements. The code below is just the last mutation, but I tried also with "on click" event on the button and everything else I found on the web. The same code works properly on the other pages, just on this one it is being submitted no matter what. Please note that the Alert is reached, so the if statement checks properly. Maybe just one clarification for this particular page, the HTML is composed by an AJAX function, that fetches some data from the backend (Flask,Python).

```js
function deleteexposedsubmit(clicked_id) {
  let deleteExposedForm = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
  let allInputInForm = deleteExposedForm.querySelectorAll("input");
  for (let i = 0; i <= allInputInForm.length; i++) {
    console.log(allInputInForm[i].name);
    console.log(allInputInForm[i].value);
    if (allInputInForm[i].name == "hasConnectedProducts" && allInputInForm[i].value == "yes") {
      alert("The Service you are trying to delete has connected consumers. Cannot be deleted");
      return false;
    } else {
      deleteExposedForm.submit();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="deleteexposedform_1" action="deleteexposed" method="POST" 
onsubmit="deleteexposedsubmit(this.id); return false;">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed" id="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed_1" value="Platform 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletename" id="selectedexposedtodeletename_1" value="Service with qualities and aspects">
  <input type="hidden" id="hasConnectedProducts1" name="hasConnectedProducts" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" id="ConnectedProducts1" name="ConnectedProducts" value="Test ingest with same qa">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletetype" id="selectedexposedtodeletetype_1" value="EPS">
  <button class="links" id="b_deleteexposedform_1" title="Press to delete the exposed service on the selected platform">delete</button></form>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you refractor your code first to make it easier to read for people.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `if` statement is inside the loop. Even through the `alert()` is shown, the `else` statement fires on successive iterations and submits the form.

To fix this store a boolean state flag in the loop and then check that *after* the loop completes.

Note the use of an unobtrusive event handler in the example below, instead of the outdated inline `onsubmit` attribute, which is bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

```js
document.querySelector('#deleteexposedform_1').addEventListener('submit', function() {
  let deleteExposedForm = this;
  let allInputInForm = deleteExposedForm.querySelectorAll("input");

  var valid = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < allInputInForm.length; i++) {
    if (allInputInForm[i].name == "hasConnectedProducts" && allInputInForm[i].value == "yes") {
      valid = false;
    }
  }

  if (!valid) {
    alert("The Service you are trying to delete has connected consumers. Cannot be deleted");
    return false;
  } else {
    deleteExposedForm.submit();
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="deleteexposedform_1" action="deleteexposed" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed" id="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed_1" value="Platform 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletename" id="selectedexposedtodeletename_1" value="Service with qualities and aspects">
  <input type="hidden" id="hasConnectedProducts1" name="hasConnectedProducts" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" id="ConnectedProducts1" name="ConnectedProducts" value="Test ingest with same qa">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletetype" id="selectedexposedtodeletetype_1" value="EPS">
  <button class="links" id="b_deleteexposedform_1" title="Press to delete the exposed service on the selected platform">delete</button>
</form>
```

As you've tagged this with jQuery, note that you can make the same logic much more succint:

```js
$('#deleteexposedform_1').on('submit', function(e) {
  var hasConnectedProducts = $(this).find('input[name="hasConnectedProducts"]').val();
  if (hasConnectedProducts === 'yes') {
    alert("The Service you are trying to delete has connected consumers. Cannot be deleted");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="deleteexposedform_1" action="deleteexposed" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed" id="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed_1" value="Platform 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletename" id="selectedexposedtodeletename_1" value="Service with qualities and aspects">
  <input type="hidden" id="hasConnectedProducts1" name="hasConnectedProducts" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" id="ConnectedProducts1" name="ConnectedProducts" value="Test ingest with same qa">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletetype" id="selectedexposedtodeletetype_1" value="EPS">
  <button class="links" id="b_deleteexposedform_1" title="Press to delete the exposed service on the selected platform">delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think my solution is simpler

Comment: Yep :) was just writing a jQuery version which was similar to that

Answer (score 0):

The form WILL submit if the function fails. Also if the first field is NOT a hasConnectedProducts, then it will submit too because of your loop logic

Instead of your code, try this:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",() => {
  document.getElementById("deleteexposedform_1").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    if (this.querySelectorAll("input[name=hasConnectedProducts][value=yes]").length > 0) {
      alert("The Service you are trying to delete has connected consumers. Cannot be deleted");
      e.preventDefault(); // now it will not submit
    }
  })   
})
```

```html
<form id="deleteexposedform_1" action="deleteexposed" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed" id="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed_1" value="Platform 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletename" id="selectedexposedtodeletename_1" value="Service with qualities and aspects">
  <input type="hidden" id="hasConnectedProducts1" name="hasConnectedProducts" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" id="ConnectedProducts1" name="ConnectedProducts" value="Test ingest with same qa">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletetype" id="selectedexposedtodeletetype_1" value="EPS">
  <button class="links" id="b_deleteexposedform_1" title="Press to delete the exposed service on the selected platform">delete</button></form>
```

**jQuery version**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#deleteexposedform_1").on("submit",function(e) {
    if ($("input[name=hasConnectedProducts][value=yes]",this).length > 0) {
      alert("The Service you are trying to delete has connected consumers. Cannot be deleted");
      e.preventDefault(); // now it will not submit
    }
  })   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="deleteexposedform_1" action="deleteexposed" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed" id="selectedplatformtodeleteexposed_1" value="Platform 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletename" id="selectedexposedtodeletename_1" value="Service with qualities and aspects">
  <input type="hidden" id="hasConnectedProducts1" name="hasConnectedProducts" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" id="ConnectedProducts1" name="ConnectedProducts" value="Test ingest with same qa">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedexposedtodeletetype" id="selectedexposedtodeletetype_1" value="EPS">
  <button class="links" id="b_deleteexposedform_1" title="Press to delete the exposed service on the selected platform">delete</button></form>
```